# why is the quadratic curve of this function not n-shaped? (displacement-time graph)

Tags: functions, curves

i have to draw a displacement-time graph of a particle that goes from A to B and when it hits B it returns back to a point C in the opposite direction. the distance AB is 4.4m an the distance CB is 0.625m when found. so i have 2 suvat equations relating s to t. (i have found them) they are:

1. $s = 3t - 0.4t^2$ for motion from A to B
2. $s = -0.4t^2 + t$ for the opposite motion from B to C.

0<t<3.25(both inclusive)

so the first one is clearly an n-shaped curve. and the second one too. however in my book the answer thats given is, the first one forms an n-shaped curve and the second one forms a u-shaped curve. can anyone explain why please?

does it have anything to do with the motion from B to C being in the opposite direction?

Comment: You've left out the necessary information to allow us to answer this. What are the exact definitions of $s$ and $t$ relative to this problem?

Comment: s is displacement and t is time.

Comment: any idea why it's this way?

Comment: When you answer the question I asked, instead of tossing out meaningless generalities, I should. But until then, the necessary information is not available.

Comment: ok. what do you want to know sir? i told you what the relationship between s and t is. there are 2 expressions relating them.

Comment: You haven't told me WHAT $s$ and $t$ are. And you've failed to recognize that even after I've tried twice to point it out to you. This suggests rather strongly that you yourself do not understand exactly what these variables represent, which is why you cannot figure out what is going on here. When you write a formula such as $s = 3t-0.4t^2$, this means that $s$ and $t$ must be *numbers*, not nebulous concepts such as "displacement" or "time". In solving any sort of problem involving physical things, the very first step is to *exactly* define how to translate those physical things to numbers.

Comment: $t$ is not just "time". It has to represent the amount of time between two events, (including the units used to measure that interval). Similarly, $s$ must represent a displacement between two points in a specific direction. For tracking the path of particle, one of two events/points defining $s$ and $t$ is "current time and location of the particle". But you have to specify what the other event/point is. That is, "time since when" and "displacement from where". This is **basic**. I strongly suspect your two formulas have different origins, which means the $t,s$ in them are not the same.